# Knockout and breeze.js take method is not working Paging

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, breeze

**Datacontext.js**

```
var manager = new breeze.EntityManager('breeze/BreezeData'); 

    function getMenuItems() {
             var query = new breeze.EntityQuery("Products").take(5);
             return manager.executeQuery(query);
         }
```

**Products.js**

```
function loadProducts() {
        return datacontext.getMenuItems().then(function (data) {
            data.results.forEach(function (item) {
                self.menuProducts.push(item);
            });
        }).fail(function (data) {
            logger.logError('Failed to load Products', null, "", true);
        });
    }
```

**Action Method**

```
 [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<MenuItem> Products()
        {
            var venueId = GetCurrentVenue().ID;
            return _contextProvider.Context.MenuItem.Where(mi => mi.Venue.ID == venueId);
        }
```

It returns almost 45 records but i am using take(5) here and that take isn't working and returning the same result.I am a newbie so i have just started to implement it.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Can you post Products action method please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change action method to:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<MenuItem> Products()
    {
        var venueId = GetCurrentVenue().ID;
        return _contextProvider.Context.MenuItem.Where(mi => mi.Venue.ID == venueId);
    }
```

In case it still doesn't work, try adding `orderBy` in case server isn't sure what would actually be first 5 items.